# Django how to get csrf_token value in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

`{% csrf_token %}` outputs a with a form field but, what if I just want the value i..e `{{ csrf_token.value }}` **is this possible? If so how?** I have searched online but cannot find any information on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `csrf_token` value is added to the context by `django.core.context_processors.csrf`, you can use it directly in the template code:

```
{{ csrf_token }}
```

This is the value used by the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag when rendering the form field.